# How to use google map waypoints for TRANSIT

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know that we are not allowed to use google map API waypoints for TRANSIT, are there any ways (possible) that we can work around this to have google map find a direction to multiple addresses in waypoints but for TRANSIT only?

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints): `As noted within the DirectionsRequest, you may also specify waypoints (of type DirectionsWaypoint) when calculating routes using the Directions service for walking, bicycling or driving directions. Waypoints are not available for transit directions.`

The only "work-around" is to make multiple independent directions requests, noting that the directions service is subject to a quota and rate limit.