# Adding multiple directions requests together Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions, map-directions

I'm trying to get directions for a user provided origin and destination, while showing directions to a middle location for ALL travel modes (driving, walking, bicycling, transit).

I have this coded using waypoints, but I just discovered that the Google Maps API doesn't support waypoints for public transit--as discussed in a previous question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004102/how-to-use-google-map-waypoints-for-transit)

I'm having difficulty finding any examples for how to go about piecing together multiple directions requests without using waypoints. Is there a way to add multiple directions to the directionsDisplay variable?

Example: Display directions from A -> B, then add directions from B -> C to the existing display.

Comment: There is an example stringing multiple directions requests together (of the same type) in this question: [Google Maps API to get bus route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315347/google-maps-api-to-get-bus-route), and another one in this question: [JavaScript Google Maps polylines : issue in connecting all given GPS locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609872/javascript-google-maps-polylines-issue-in-connecting-all-given-gps-locations)

Comment: @geocodezip Those are a little off from my question. I just found this question though: [Multiple travel modes to render one map using google maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922856/multiple-travel-modes-to-render-one-map-using-google-maps-api) and it seems a little more closer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer based on this question: [Multiple travel modes to render one map using google maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922856/multiple-travel-modes-to-render-one-map-using-google-maps-api)

Multiple directionsDisplays are needed, with multiple trip legs (requests) being sent to directionsService.route().